# Coefficients of a Natural Log Power Series

Tags: calculus

**The Problem:**

The function $f(x)=\ln(1−x^2)$ is represented as a power series with:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty c(n) \cdot  x^n$$

Find the FOLLOWING coefficients in the power series.

**Current Progress:**

So with this series, you need to differentiate by individual parts. The derivative of $\ln(1-x^2)$ is $\frac {-2x}{1-x^2}$.

Pulling out the $-2x $ from the numerator, you get the ratio of the series as $x^2$. This means that the sum of the series must be

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty -2x^{2n + 1}$$

Taking the individual terms of the series and then taking their antiderivative, I get for the coefficients:

$$-1, -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, \ldots$$

But this is wrong, apparently. What SHOULD be the coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined for $-1<x<1$. Consider $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$, so
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{1-x}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
$$
Then, since $f(0)=1$, we have, over $(-1,1)$,
$$
f(x)=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
Therefore, over the same interval,
$$
f(-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
and, finally,
$$
\ln(1-x^2)=f(x)+f(-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+(-1)^n)\frac{x^n}{n}
$$
Thus
$$
c(0)=0,\quad c(1)=0,\quad c(2)=-1,\quad c(3)=0,\quad c(4)=-1/2,\quad\dots
$$
In general
$$
c(n)=\begin{cases}
0 & n=0,\\
0 & n\text{ is odd}\\
-2/n & n\ge2\text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Since the function $\ln(1-x^2)$ is even, the coefficients of the odd powers of $x$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients of the even-numbered terms are indeed $-1$, $-1/2$, $-1/3$, $-1/4$, $\ldots$.  But you forgot the odd-numbered terms, whose coefficients are $0$.